# jquery check div class exists after another certain class

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, drupal

So I know there is jquery that can find a specific class on a page, and I know there is jquery to find descendants of another class. But I am looking for help on something different.

I am using a Drupal view and the infinite scroll module. As new items appear as you scroll down I want a `<hr>`  to appear after the div class "views-row-last". So the hr would be outside that div but before the next div.

So I am trying to find jquery to search for the hr but add it to last div if it does not exist. I can kind of get it to work with one of their functions of their provided js files:

```
load: function() {
            $('div#views_infinite_scroll-ajax-loader').remove();
            Drupal.attachBehaviors(this);

             jQuery("<hr class='rule' style='clear:both' />").insertAfter(".views-row-last");
          }
```

The issue is that each time a new set of items loads it adds the same hr line to the previously added line, so two lines appears, then three, then four, etc. I need help to check whether a hr exists after "div class="views-row-last" and if it does not, to actually add it but as a separate element.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove before adding it to DOM. Try this:

```
load: function() {
            $('div#views_infinite_scroll-ajax-loader').remove();
            Drupal.attachBehaviors(this);
             jQuery('hr.rule').remove(); // remove hr before appending it.
             jQuery("<hr class='rule' style='clear:both' />").insertAfter(".views-row-last");
          }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zSx8a/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm, I tried to use the remove() before but I added it after the insertAfter function

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching too far, you could simply use `:last` pseudo class :

```
jQuery("<hr class='rule' style='clear:both' />").insertAfter(".views-row-last:last");
```

In case the check is really impotant, you could use next/prev trick:

```
jQuery("<hr class='rule' style='clear:both' />").insertAfter(
    $(".views-row-last").not($(".views-row-last").next('.rule').prev())
 );
```

Or filter :

```
jQuery("<hr class='rule' style='clear:both' />").insertAfter(
    $(".views-row-last").filter(function(){
        return !$(this).next('.ruler').length;
    })
 );
```